# Snap Framework Compile error during fresh install

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I'm receiving the following error when installing Snap for the first time.  I've tried installing heist first but get the same error.  I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 32bit desktop (brand new installation) and ghc 7.4.1.

Anyone else get this error? Solution?
Thanks.

```
[18 of 29] Compiling Snap.Snaplet.HeistNoClass ( src/Snap/Snaplet/HeistNoClass.hs, dist/build/Snap/Snaplet/HeistNoClass.o )

src/Snap/Snaplet/HeistNoClass.hs:195:32:
Couldn't match expected type `n0 (Either e'0 b0)'
            with actual type `Text'
Expected type: String -> n0 (Either e'0 b0)
  Actual type: String -> Text
In the first argument of `(.)', namely `T.pack'
In the first argument of `mapEitherT', namely
  `(T.pack . intercalate "")'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
sample1-0.1 depends on snap-0.10.0.1 which failed to install.
snap-0.10.0.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
snaplet-sqlite-simple-0.4.0 depends on snap-0.10.0.1 which failed to install.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependecy of [`errors`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors) on [`either`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/either) is specified as `either >= 3.0.1`, and `either` isn't listed as a build-dependency for [`snap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap) (since the used module `Control.Monad.Trans.Either` is re-exported from `Control.Error`, that isn't necessary, even though `snap` directly uses code from `either`). Thus building `snap` pulls in the latest version of `either`.

However, in `either-3.1`, the type of `mapEitherT` changed. It used to be

```
mapEitherT :: Functor m => (e -> f) -> (a -> b) -> EitherT e m a -> EitherT f m b
```

in `either-3.0.*`, and now it is

```
mapEitherT :: (m (Either e a) -> n (Either e' b)) -> EitherT e m a -> EitherT e' n b
```

The code was written for the old version.

You can constrain the version of `either` to use,

```
cabal install snaplet-sqlite-simple --constraint="either < 3.1"
```

to build it.

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded snap 0.11 to hackage, which should also fix the problem.